# Python: Checking if a key is part of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make my own irc bot (for twitch) in Python. I have a dictionary with my commands:

```
commands = {

    '!ping': {
        'cooldown': 30,
        'return': '!pong'
    },

    '!random': {
        'cooldown': 30,
        'return': 'command',
        'argc': 2,
        'arg_username': True,
        'usage': '!random <min> <max>'
    }

} # End of commands
```

Then I have a function to check if the message that was send is indeed a command:

```
import string

def is_valid_command(command):
    return True if command in commands.keys() else False
```

So when i test this function out, it don't seems to work, and I don't know what I am doiing wrong:

```
message = "!ping"
print(str(is_valid_command(message)))
>>> False
```

I tried to change '!ping' inside the dictionary to "!ping", and virsa versa with the message, even deleted the '!' and it always says it's False.

Thanks in regards,
Laurens

EDIT:

```
def is_valid_command(command):
    for key in commands.keys():
        print(key)
    print("input " + str(command))
    print(command in commands.keys())
    return command in commands.keys()
```

This result in this:

```
!ping
!random
input !ping
False
```

EDIT2: @e4c5 wanted me to use try/except, as i quickly try it (inside that methode), it still return False

```
try:
    cmd = commands[command]
    print ('Try True')
    return True
except KeyError:
    print('Try False')
    return False
```

EDIT3: u'!ping' before fixed this (message = u'!ping'), but when I read a string from somewhere else, is there a function that does this unicoding?

Comment: Which version of python are you using ? What you provided return True for me, not False, on python 3.x

Comment: First of all you can simplify the body of `is_valid_command` to `return command in commands.keys()`. Secondly, your code returns True

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 and it returns ``True`` to me.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 and I placed it all in 1 file, and still returns false for me

Comment: Are you using a standard keyboard? This is maybe stupid idea, but maybe some of the characters is non ASCII or something.

Comment: I know it looks stupid, I'm sitting here already 3 hours looking at this stupid thing... I even re-typed it twice...

Comment: Small hint: use `for key in commands:`, which is the same as your `for key in commands.keys():`.

Comment: Doesn't that result in a false True if i would have the key as a value?
commands[key1] = value1
commands[key2] = key1

Comment: Could you please do me a favor? Put a simple u' ' behind your strings...just to check (this means unicode..... u'!ping' for instance and as well when you call the function)

Comment: @Laurens Sorry, I didn't mean that your code is stupid (I meant my idea). It's really fine. I thought that maybe some letter in a string are not encoded properly. And as Marco smdm suggested try making a string unicode by adding u''.

Comment: @Marcosmdm before or afther string? you say afther, but show u'!ping'

Comment: It gave error when i put it afther

Comment: fixed it whe i put it in front, thanks

Comment: of course before.....always in the beginning as showed.....   u'!ping'

Comment: Add ``u`` before a string. Like ``u'!ping``. Try adding the ``u`` in message first, and then add it both in message and in dictionary to test.

Comment: Now it works, but when I read a message from the irc chat, i can't put a u before it, as it is already a variable, is there a methode that does this?

Comment: Maybe you can do ``message_from_irc + u''``? Also, this may be the error because you're coding using a keyboard with a non-english language. I'd suggest switching to english layout when coding to avoid this types of mistakes in the future. And also, you can do this ``unicode(message_from_irc)`` this is probably the better solution.

Comment: Just put as u'%s' % message and that's it ;) Happy that something works!

Comment: thanks @Marcosmdm, problem was that passing it from the irc it had a \r at the end, so i've split it message[-2:] to leave last two characters out, and then it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not returning just:

```
return command in commands.keys()
```

That should be True/False already! hope this clarify!

As mentioned above to create a unicode string out of your messages just:

```
u'%s' % message
```

Comment: Even shorter, but I like to specify everytime the keys, looks nicer. @Laurens in my case it is working....mmmm

Comment: I have tested both functions shared above in py2 and py3 and both are giving me True :-)

Comment: @Laurens did it show now correctly with the u' !string' trick?

Comment: @Laurens I gotta go...but I hope my answer solved your query ;) Last trick to set your unicode as default...you can use on top of your file reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') ....but in this case this is not needed! Ciao and have a nice day!

Comment: the probem was that there was a \r at the end of the message while passing it towards the function, that's why it was false

Answer (score 6):

Your `is_valid_command` function can be simplified to:

```
def is_valid_command(command):
    return command in commands
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your script and it seems to work fine.

Did some simplifications, but basically have the same code as you.

```
commands = {
    '!ping': {
        'cooldown': 30,
        'return': '!pong'
    },
    '!random': {
        'cooldown': 30,
        'return': 'command',
        'argc': 2,
        'arg_username': True,
        'usage': '!random <min> <max>'
    }
}

def is_valid_command(command):
    return command in commands.keys()

print(is_valid_command("!ping"))
```

Which returns `True`. If I try command `!pong` it returns `False`.

Comment: Agree with you :-)

Comment: I editied my first post, I visual see it's the same... but it still returns false.. any clues?

Comment: @Laurens I tried the code you edited. It works as well. Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Does not seem to be a code problem from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

This pre checking is not needed and unpythonic. Instead of all these ccomplications, just do

```
try:
   cmd = commands[message]
   # do whatever with cmd
except KeyError:
   print ('Sorry not a valid command')
```

[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many
>   other languages such as C.

Comment: I have a lot more to do in the else statement too... That's why I didn't choose for try/except

Comment: Well put what goes into the `else` into the `except` which is in fact the standard way of doing this.

Comment: Will do once this issue is solved, becose when i will put it into a try/except, it will still go to the except as it didn't find the key

Comment: Well you don't need to solve this issue. That's the whole point. A waste of time and effort to do things in the unpythonic way while the pythonic way is shorter, and simpler and possibly faster for large number of iterations (because of avoiding an extra function call)

Comment: Little addition: to always return a default value, use `cmd = commands.get(message, default)`. That way you can completely avoid the `KeyError`.

Comment: @ChristianKönig that's an alternative way of doing things. That is not needed when you do the Ask For Forgiveness approach. If the OP insists on writing unpythonic code, he can definitely use your approach insead of the complicated command in command.keys() stuff

Comment: Thanks, i'll remember in the future

Answer (score 0):

I am using python2.7  and your code returns True for me.

Instead of writing function, you can directly use :

`message = "!ping"
print(commands.has_key(message))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a function to convert a string to unicode. Use `unicode` function e.g. `unicode('my_string')`.

For example if your message from irc is stored in a variable `message_from_irc` then you can convert it as `unicode(message_from_irc)`.

I suggest you switch keyboard language to English when coding, in order to avoid this types of unexpected behaviors of code.